# How can i solve small image not visible error

Tags: magento-1.9, image

The product consists the 3 sides of images, but front end only visible 2 images only.

[image]

Comment: can you  uncheck  exclude box and save the product and try once.

Comment: what is mean exclude ??

Comment: in the backend, can you see text "exclude" you can see in image you posted, you have selected that checkbox , once you uncheck it and save the product and than check in frontend. for the first image, in the  last but one column, you selected checkbox, you have to remove it.

Comment: yes bro, i got what to try to tell me, but my question is what is the option exclude, purpose of that.

Comment: okay, suppose we uploaded some images, for tempararily we want to hide those images, so we will select `exclude` checkbox. later if you want to display those images, you can uncheck the box. as Great magento devoloper said `This is  feature not a bug`

Comment: @JeevaRathinam Exclude will eliminate the image from displaying. But it will not remove the image.

Comment: i am imported 1000 products like exclude option, how can i remove bulk edit.

Answer (score 1):

As per as,you screen , you  **have remove first image from galley list** using  ***checkbox on  Exclude*** box.You need to `uncheck` this box for showing that  imges in ***below thumbails list***